# How to use dictionary in class? it shows the dict is not defined

Tags: python, class, dictionary, undefined

I do define the dictionary, but it keeps sayingt that the dictionary "ROOMS" is not defined.

First I thought it was because the dict was outside the class, but when I put it in the class, it still shows the same information.

Then I want to know how to refer to a dictionary in class?
Thanks to the first answer, I have already tried self.ROOMS and it worked. But what if I have many dicts, do I have to put them all in method **init**?? But it is recommended in "Learn python the hard way" that we'd better not put so much under **init**

code is attached here,and unrelated part has been minimized.

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint


class Game(object):


    def __init__ (self, start):
        self.quips = ['You died.you kinda suck at this.', 'Nice job, you died...jackass.',
            "Such a luser.",
            'I have a small puppy that\'s bettr at this.']
        self.start = start

    def play (self):
        next = self.start

        while True:
            print "\n--------"
            room = ROOMS[next]
            next = room()

    def death(self):

        print self.quips[randint(0,len(quips)-1)]
        exit(1)


    def central_corridor(self):

        action = raw_input(">")

        if action == "shoot!":

            return 'death'

        elif action == "dodge!":

            return 'death'

        elif action == "tell a joke":

            return 'laser_weapon_armory'

        else :
            print "DOES NOT COMPUTE!"
            return 'central_corridor'



    def laser_weapon_armory(self):

        code = "%d%d%d" %(randint(1,9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))
        guess = raw_input("[keypad]>")
        guesses = 0

        while guess != code and guesses < 10:
            print "BZZZZEDDD!"
            guesses += 1 
            guess = raw_input("[keypad]>")

        if guess == code:

            return 'the_bridge'
        else:

            return 'death'

    def the_bridge(self):

        action = raw_input("> ")

        if action == "throw the bomb":

            return 'death'

        elif action == "slowly place the bomb":

            return 'escape_pod'
        else:   
            print "DOES NOT COMPUTE!"
            return "the_bridge"

    def escape_pod(self):


        good_pod = randint(1,5)
        guess = raw_input("[pod#]> ")


        if int(guess) != good_pod:

            return 'death'

        else:

            exit(0)


    ROOMS = {
              'death' : death,
              'central_corridor' : central_corridor,
              'laser_weapon_armory' : laser_weapon_armory,
              'the_bridge' : the_bridge,
              'escape_pod' : escape_pod
      }


a_game = Game("central_corridor")
a_game.play()
```

Comment: What happens if you move the ROOMS dictionary to the top, just under your init method and call it `self.rooms`?

Comment: @akonsu `self.ROOMS` wouldn't work as its not an instance variable, OP would need to do `Game.ROOMS` instead.

Comment: I really did try and figure out a suitable answer to this question OP, but the answer is `There are too many errors in your code. Would you like to try again? Y/N`.

Comment: @Lego Stormtroopr i copied from "learn python the hard way", and it works well in my computer, if don't use the dict. So, what type of error you mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the definition of `ROOMS` into the `__init__` method of your class and refer to it later as `self.ROOMS` and also prepend `self.` to the function names ....

```
class Game(object):


    def __init__ (self, start):
        self.quips = ['You died.you kinda suck at this.', 'Nice job, you died...jackass.',
            "Such a luser.",
            'I have a small puppy that\'s bettr at this.']
        self.start = start


        self.ROOMS = {
            'death' : self.death,
            'central_corridor' : self.central_corridor,
            'laser_weapon_armory' : self.laser_weapon_armory,
            'the_bridge' : self.the_bridge,
            'escape_pod' : self.escape_pod
        }

    def play (self):
        next = self.start

        while True:
            print "\n--------"
            room = self.ROOMS[next]
            next = room()
```

Comment: what if i need a lot of dicts? should I put them all in the __init__ method?? it there any other ways to refer to a dict in a class??